# Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element' Angular 4 (Chip with Autocomplete)

Tags: angular, typescript

i was trying to implement chips with autocomplete in angular 4, i found this package for chips with autocomplete. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips

But when i try to implement i am getting below error not sure what casuing this error could someone please help on fixing this error. Is there any components available for chips autocomplete in angular 4 ?

**Console Error:**

```
browser.es5.js:4670 Invalid keyframe value for property height: -16px core.es5.js:1020 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.
```

code :

```
           <div class="destination">
                <tag-input  formControlName="Destination" [placeholder]="'Destination'" [modelAsStrings]="true" [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Destination'" [maxItems]='5' [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true">
                        <tag-input-dropdown [minimumTextLength]='3' [limitItemsTo]='4' [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="AirportsDetails">
                        </tag-input-dropdown>
                </tag-input>  
            </div>
```

Is there any options to remove animations or ignore animation to fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you have the code of the animation that is being triggered for us? The reason why the animation can't be executed is because you give a height of -16px and HTML/CSS doesn't accept that value.

Comment: no i am not sure from where it get trigger, is there any options to ignore this animation and fix error  manually with code :(